# Is it true in general that $f (A_ 1 ∩A_ 2 ) = f (A_ 1 )∩f (A_ 2 )$ for every subsets $A_ 1 , A_ 2$ of $ A$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it true in general that $f (A_ 1 ∩A_ 2 ) = f (A_ 1 )∩f (A_ 2 )$ for every subsets $A_ 1 , A_ 2$ of $A$? Please someone help me

Comment: what ? what is $f$ ?

Comment: $f:A\to B$ is a function

Comment: oh ok I understood you meant "the image of $A_1$ by $f$", so the answer is trivially yes for $\cup$ not for $\cap$.

Comment: @reuns No it is not.

Comment: for $\cup$ it is

Comment: That isn't what you had initially written.

Comment: If $f$ is injective, then $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ does hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have is $f\left(A_1\cap A_2\right) \subseteq f\left(A_1\right)\cap f\left(A_2\right)$, but the other way around need not hold.  For example, let $f:\{1,2,3\}\to\{1,2,3\}$ be defined by $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, and $f(3)=2$.
What happens if $A_1=\{1,2\}$ and $A_2=\{1,3\}$?

Answer (score 8):

In general case no! because $f$ can be constant function and $A_1$ and $A_2$ can be disjoint then we will have $f(A_1)=f(A_2)$ but $A_1\cap A_2=\phi$

Comment: This is a basic yet perfect example.  If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (i.e., $A \cap B = \emptyset)$, then $f(A \cap B) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $f(A) \cap f(B)$ need not be empty, so we can have $f(A \cap B) \subsetneq f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, equality is not the case here.  Instead, this is the case:

$$ f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $A = \mathbb{R} $ and $A_1 = (-1,0) $, $A_2 = (0,1) $ and let $f: x \to x^2 $, Notice

$$ f(A_1 \cap A_2 ) = f( \varnothing ) = \varnothing $$

Whereas

$$ f(A_1) = f(A_2) = (0,1) $$